# Excluding JRE jars from Eclipse searches?

Tags: java, eclipse

If I use Ctrl-G to search for declarations of an overridden Java method in my Eclipse workspace, I end up with several hundred results found in jar files located outside my workspace (in C:\Program Files\Java...). I have tried everything I can think f (filter settings etc.) but have been unable to find any way to prevent this.

How I can persuade Eclipse not to search my entire computer for results?

Comment: Use _Search > Java Search_ without the option _JRE libraries_ for that.

Comment: In the search dialog (ctrl-H), JRE libraries is already unchecked. Is that what you meant? I want it to apply to ctrl-G (search for declarations). Ctrl-shift-G (search for references) is OK, because references to my code are only found in my code), but declarations of commonly-used names like  "getType()" finds hundreds of declarations of methods with that name in the JRE jars.

Comment: This is not what I meant. When using the _Declaration in Workspace_ (Ctrl+G) command, in the _Search_ view you have to _Group by Project_ and it has to be _Show as Tree_, then you can look only into the source folders and "manually" ignore the system library and dependencies (you can also select search results you are not interested in and hit _Delete_ to remove them). Alternatively, use _Java Search_ to not search in the system library and in dependencies at all.

Comment: Yes, I have Group by Project and Show as Tree. I see an couple of dozen jar files with my "src" folder somewhere in the middle. I can then select all except "src" and hit delete -- but I'd prefer that it would filter out this stuff automatically. Ctrl-G is billed as "search in workspace" -- I can laboriously right-click and select "search references by hierarchy", which seems to give me results just from my code. If I could rebind ctrl-G to mean "search hierarchy", that would probably do the trick, but otherwise searching for declarations is a lot more work than I think it should be.

Comment: To specify a shortcut, hit Ctrl+Sift+L twice and add a new binding for one of the _References/Declaration in Workspace/Project/Hierarchy_ commands. You can also right-click and choose _Declarations > Working Set..._ to specify a search scope that can be used in _References/Declarations in Working Set_, but that command will always show a dialog to choose a working set as search scope. Java Search (Ctrl+H) will also show a dialog each time, but the settings will be remembered, so that in most cases just hitting Ctrl+H and then Enter (to close the search dialog) will work.

Comment: Many thanks. "To specify a shortcut, hit Ctrl+Sift+L twice and add a new binding for one of the References/Declaration in Workspace/Project/Hierarchy commands." However, I unbound Ctrl+G from Declarations in Workspace (In Windows) and bound it to Declarations in Hierarchy (In Windows), but it doesn't work -- the shortcut doesn't appear on the menu, and pressing Ctrl+G does nothing (but selecting from the menu still works). I tried restarting Eclipse "just in case", but that didn't help, nor did changing "When" to "Editing Java source". I'm obviously being a bit stupid somehow!

Comment: Depending which Eclipse IDE package you have, there might be the same named command twice, but only one of them refers to Java.

Comment: I'm still using Oxygen with Java 1.8 (old, but it works, and without a good reason to upgrade I just can't be bothered). Thanks for all the help -- I'll keep plugging away at it, and will report back if I find out how to rebind Ctrl+G successfully.

Comment: Performance, new features and security are the reasons why you should keep your software up to date. I hope the users of the applications you develop don't think the same way.